# Why won't this recursive caesar cipher algorithm work?

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

```
def encrypt(plaintext, key):
    if key == 0:
        ciphertext = plaintext
        return ciphertext

    key %= 26
    ciphertext = ""
    for letter in plaintext:
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter.isupper():
                new_letter = chr((ord(letter) - 65 + key) % 26 + 65)
            else:
                new_letter = chr((ord(letter) - 97 + key) % 26 + 97)
            ciphertext += new_letter
        else:
            ciphertext += letter

    return encrypt(ciphertext, key - 1)
```

If I input "hello" and the key is 2, then I should get "jgnnq" but I get "khoor". The program only wirks if the key is 1. Does anyon know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you *expect* that program to do? Generally running Caesar-cipher multiple times is totally pointless as it will always be "shift by some value" at the end - so all you need is to figure out the shift and encode all letters once...

Comment: @jarmod That would make the code non-recursive...

Comment: Try using `ord(letter) - 64` and `ord(letter) - 96` instead of `ord(letter) - 65 + key` and `ord(letter) - 97 + key`. But also couldn't you just use `chr(ord(letter) + 1)` instead of `chr((ord(letter) - 65 + key) % 26 + 65)`? In the second case you are unnecessarily complicating your code by subtracting 65 and adding it again.

Comment: @jasonharper why is it an insane way? I am new to all this, can you please explain why?

Comment: It's insane because recursion is utterly unnecessary to solve this problem.  In fact, you had the right answer in the original call to the function - the only thing that recursion did was change that right answer into a wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Because you replace the value when the recursive iterates

```
def encrypt(plaintext, key):
    if key == 0:
        ciphertext = plaintext
        return ciphertext

    key %= 26
    print(key)
    ciphertext = ""
    for letter in plaintext:
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter.isupper():
                new_letter = chr((ord(letter) - 65 + key) % 26 + 65)
            else:
                new_letter = chr((ord(letter) - 97 + key) % 26 + 97)

            ciphertext += new_letter
        else:
            ciphertext += letter
    print(ciphertext)

    return encrypt(ciphertext, key - 1)

encrypt("hello", 2)
```

Output:

```
2
jgnnq
1
khoor
```

So if you want jgnnq. Why you create recursive?

Edited under your comment:

```
def encrypt(plaintext, key, i = 0, ciphertext=''):
    k = key
    if key == 0:
        ciphertext = plaintext
        return ciphertext

    key %= 26
    letter = plaintext[i]
    if letter.isalpha():
        if letter.isupper():
            new_letter = chr((ord(letter) - 65 + key) % 26 + 65)
        else:
            new_letter = chr((ord(letter) - 97 + key) % 26 + 97)

        ciphertext += new_letter
    else:
        ciphertext += letter
    i+=1
    if len(ciphertext) == len(plaintext):
        return ciphertext
    return encrypt(plaintext, k, i, ciphertext)

encrypt("hello", 2)
```

Output:

```
'jgnnq'
```

Comment: This was a requirement for the code. I'd appreciate any help fixing it